# cakephp functions that should take about 100 milliseconds at most take much longer

Tags: optimization, cakephp-2.0

My app is being used for 6 months and I've stopped being asked to solve new bugs a long while ago.. life was great :)

Now I finished working on other projects and would like to speed things up with my application.

**PROBLEM**

E.G.: I have a very simple function like this, that I call using AJAX.

In the browser console I see, that the function takes 700 miliseconds to finish. I counted how much millis does it take for the actual code in the body of the function to fire. Not surprisingly, only about 100 milliseconds, which would be OK.

```
public function getObjVisibility() 
{
    $start = round( microtime( true ) * 1000 );

    $this->autoRender = false;
    $tmp = $this->Obj->find ( 'first', array 
        (
            'conditions' => array 
            ( 
                'obj_id' => $_POST['id']
            ),
            'fields' => array
            (
                'visible'
            )
        )
    );
    $result = $tmp['Obj']['visible']; //added field so I could count even the assigning

    $end = round( microtime ( true ) * 1000 );
    fb::log( "time: ", $start - $end ); // firePHP logging to console

    return $tmp['Obj']['visible'];
}
```

So the function should take at most about 100 millis, takes at least about 700.

Does any of you have any idea what's going on? I was unable to formulate a reasonable question for the google to give me a reasonable answer, so I asked you guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cake request/response goes through dispatch, routing, rendering, etc... so it is more than just the body of that action. Have you tried the [DebugKit](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42880/home)? It has some profiling features which might help you isolate slow parts.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer -> new debug tool and the info about dispatch, routing, etc. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for these problems to occur was obviously the fact, that my application takes several synchronized AJAX calls to perform some actions.

As I was synchronizing and asynchronizing my calls during the implementation I did not think about the packets that have to be sent and received from the server and am sending several small requests, which each take some time to load depending on the clients connection.

I am solving this by resynchronizing the app ( deleting `async: false` parameter from jQuery AJAX call ) and/or getting several information from the server via one request.

If you think this is a bad idea, let me know :-)